# Region server issue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am getting warning like these when region server stopped every time. Any suggestions please

```
WARN  [regionserver60020.compactionChecker] util.Sleeper: **We slept 36092ms instead of 10000ms,** t**his is likely due to a long garbage collecting pause and it's usually bad, see http://hbase.apache.org/book.html
#trouble.rs.runtime.zkexpired**

regionserver60020] util.Sleeper: We slept 19184ms instead of 3000ms, this is likely due to a long garbage collecting pause and it's usually bad, see http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#trouble.rs.runtime.zkexpired

2015-10-08 04:11:33,030 INFO  [regionserver60020-SendThread(xxxx)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 24827ms for sessionid 0x54ee10bc6f21c05, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

2015-10-08 04:11:33,030 INFO  [SplitLogWorker-xxxx,60020,1443823580220-SendThread( xxxx:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 24356ms for sessionid 0x44ee10bc6361c47, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect


2015-10-08 04:11:33,607 INFO  [SplitLogWorker-xxx,60020,1443823580220-SendThread(xxxxx)] client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will use GSSAPI as SASL mechanism.

2015-10-08 22:46:15,211 WARN  [main-SendThread(xxxxxxx)] client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Zookeeper client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. Make sure that the client is configured to use a ticket cache (using the JAAS configuration setting 'useTicketCache=true)' and restart the client. If you still get this message after that, the TGT in the ticket cache has expired and must be manually refreshed. To do so, first determine if you are using a password or a keytab. If the former, run kinit in a Unix shell in the environment of the user who is running this Zookeeper client using the command 'kinit <princ>' (where <princ> is the name of the client's Kerberos principal). If the latter, do 'kinit -k -t <keytab> <princ>' (where <princ> is the name of the Kerberos principal, and <keytab> is the location of the keytab file). After manually refreshing your cache, restart this client. If you continue to see this message after manually refreshing your cache, ensure that your KDC host's clock is in sync with this host's clock.

2015-10-08 22:46:15,919 WARN  [main-SendThread(xxxxxxxx)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Checksum failed Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it.
```

Comment: Please reformat your questions and make clear what is code, log and your comments, as well as what exactly do you need help with.

Comment: @Sebastian i am getting these error only whenever region server stopped.

Comment: @Sebastian I have attaches some more log on above please  check it.